# Java counting letters from a string text

Tags: java

i got a problem with my code. it is working and it does count the letters.
but my problem is that it returns f.e. A= multiple times and then B= multiple times and so on and so on.
anyway here is my code: thanks for the help :)

```
String text="Endlich wieder Schule!! Einen solchen Seufzer kann nur ausstossen, dessen Ferien scheusslich und die Erinnerung an das vergangene Schuljahr wunderbar waren: Harry Potter. Doch wie im Vorjahr stehen nicht nur Zaubertrankunterricht und Verwandlung auf dem Programm. Ein grauenhafter Zyklop treibt sein Unwesen in den Gemaeuern der Schule ein Ungeheuer, fuer das niemand, nicht einmal der maechtigste Zauberer, eine Erklaerung findet. Wird Harry mit Hilfe seiner Freunde Ron und Hermine das Raetsel loesen und Hogwarts aus der Umklammerung durch die dunklen Maechte befreien koennen?";

    int count;

    for (char letter=(char)65;letter<=90;letter++){
        count=0;

        for (int i=0; i<text.length(); i++){

            if (letter==text.charAt(i) || (letter+32)==text.charAt(i)){
            count++;
            }

                if (count>0){
                    System.out.println(letter+" = "+count);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your results.  You need to move the if (count) block outside of the for loop.  Also, you defined count as an int.  I think you want a dictionary with each different letter and its associated count.  Try it with ABCABA and show the results you get, and what you want in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the inner loop from :

```
    for (int i=0; i<text.length(); i++){

        if (letter==text.charAt(i) || (letter+32)==text.charAt(i)){
        count++;
        }

            if (count>0){
                System.out.println(letter+" = "+count);
            }
    }
```

to

```
for (int i=0; i<text.length(); i++){
    if (letter==text.charAt(i) || (letter+32)==text.charAt(i)){
        count++;
    }
}

if (count>0){
    System.out.println(letter+" = "+count);
}
```

You had to print the result **after the inner loop** terminates.